# How to store values for each user for each server

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, discord.py

This is going to be more of an abstract question, since there's no code I can provide related to this question. I'm a bit new to working with databases, so I'm not familiar with conventional designs (yet).

I have these tables: `users` and `servers`.

I currently have a method of keeping score for each user by incrementing the `score` field in the `users` table. However, this results in global scores, which is fine, but I would like to be able to track server-specific scores as well.

What would be the best approach for keeping a `user`'s score for each `server` they use?

Comment: You could have a table `scores` that has `(userid, serverid, score)`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Thanks for the idea. I'll be trying it out

Comment: But to ensure a proper normalized design, if you create such a new `score` table, you should eliminate the score column in the `users` table.  Don't store the total in the `users` table.  To get the overall total score you would then do a query to sum all the scores in the `scores` table.

Answer (score 0):

To track server specific scores you can just add a table with servers ids by using `guild.id`.

Answer (score 0):

You could have User(user.id) | Server(guild.id) | score

Then to track the server score find all the records for that server and add the score to a global variable.

This is an example in pseudocode/python

```
total = 0
for x in Server:
    total += x[score]
```